# There is a text inside a block in starship command prompt

Tags: command-line, snap

There is a text F583 written inside a block in gnome terminal in ubuntu 22.04. Gnome terminal using bash shell and starship command prompt install from snap store ( sudo snap install starship).
Tried using this tutorial by distrotube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5b-xQkRWHjQ&t=345s

Comment: Hello. What's the actual question here? You have provided no details anyone can work with to help with the issue (whatever it might be)...

Answer (score 0):

this issue has to do with system fonts

the box with the text "f583" is suppose to be a battery icon. If you go to https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet and type in f583 it should return an image of a battery icon. since your system does not have that icon installed, it just displays a generic box icon with the corresponding icon code

you need to use an icon font patcher like nerd fonts (https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) in order for the icons to display correctly.